# Is there a way to flush a directory pointer?

Tags: c, fork, fflush

I am trying to use fork to sort files in directories. I have my mergesort code, but I am trying to figure out how to use fork before I implement it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "scannerCSVsorter.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    char buffer[100];
    getcwd(buffer,100);
    traverse(buffer);

    return 0;
}

void traverse(char *name){

    DIR *direc;
    struct dirent *dirent_n;    

    direc = opendir(name);
    chdir(name);

    while((dirent_n = readdir(direc)) != NULL){        
        if(isDir(dirent_n->d_name) != 0){
            if(!strcmp(dirent_n->d_name,".") || !strcmp(dirent_n- 
            >d_name,"..")){ //avoid the current and parent directory
                continue;
            }
            printf("%s is a directory\n", dirent_n->d_name);
            fork();
            printf("%d\n", getpid());
            if(getpid() == -1){
                printf("failure to create child\n");
                return;
            }
            traverse(dirent_n->d_name);
        }
        else{
            pid_t child = fork();
            if(getpid() == -1){
                printf("failure to create child\n");                
                return;
            }
            if(getpid() == child){
                printf("%s is a file\n", dirent_n->d_name);
                return;
            }

        }

    }
    return;
}

int isDir(char name[]){
    struct stat state;
    if(stat(name, &state) != 0)
        return 0;
    return S_ISDIR(state.st_mode);
}
```

This is my output

```
-Movie_megadata is a directory
-Movie_megadata is a directory
-7715
-7716
-7717
-7718
-number 2 is a directory
-number 2 is a directory
-number 2 is a directory
-number 2 is a directory
-7715
-7720
-7723
-number 2 is a directory
-7719
-7728
-7726
-7727
-7721
-number 2 is a directory
-number 2 is a directory
-number 2 is a directory
-number 2 is a directory
-number 2 is a directory
-number 2 is a directory
-number 2 is a directory
-7716
-7718
-7736
-7717
-7730
-7725
-number 2 is a directory
-7731
-number 2 is a directory
-7729
-number 2 is a directory
-7739
-7735
-7740
-7738
-7732
-7742
-7741
-7722
-7733
-number 2 is a directory
-7744
-7724
```

I think this is due to not flushing my pointer and the fork restarting the loop. I have tried fflush(stdout), but I get the same error. Is there a way to flush a directory pointer.

Comment: "*I am trying to use fork to sort files in directories*" - but why?

Comment: Do you want to change the order of files in directories(??) or just list them in sorted order? And why is this output bad, what is the expected output?

Comment: When you do `fork`, you don't remember the return (i.e. non-zero is parent and zero is child, -1=error). You have to compare _this_ against -1 (i.e. `getpid` will _not_ work). Also, the parent doesn't do `wait`, so you end up with zombie processes. Note that `readdir` returns a `struct dirent` that [usually] has a `d_type` entry that you can compare against `DT_DIR`, so you can probably skip the `stat` call. Also, doing a `fork` _just_ to determine whether an entry is a file or not [in your `else`] probably doesn't work too well either--it's already _known_ to be a file.

Comment: What do you mean by 'flushing a directory pointer'?  They're an input-only stream, so there's no output to flush, and AFAIK, the `opendir()` set of functions doesn't provide a `flushdir()` function.  When the fork occurs, the two processes each end up with a copy of the original directory stream; you might or might not want to rewind one of the two streams after the `fork()`, or you might want one or the other of the processes to close the stream.  Your problem is probably not related to flushing the `DIR *` variable.

Comment: Its for a project with set instructions. We are just trying to print if its a file or directory than we will incorporate mergesort to sort the contents in the file and output the sorted directory in one large directory in STDOUT. its a test directory with F F (D-(F)). We get it to work without Fork, but it looks like it's calling fork, but printf isn't flushed to stdout yet